# Bluepill - installed in user RVM - project specific gemset - how to run with sudo without password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, bluepill

I have Bluepill setup to monitor my delayed_job processes.

On my production server, I use RVM installed in the user's home folder (username is `deploy`). My app's gems are installed in its own project-specific gemset. So, the bluepill gem and its corresponding binary are installed within the `~/.rvm/....` folder.

When I deploy my app using capistrano, I want bluepill to be stopped and started, so my DJs get restarted. I am looking at the instructions for the capistrano recipe [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2010/02/monitoring-delayed-job-with-bluepill-and-capistrano/).

I think my RVM-compliant bluepill tasks have to be like the following:

```
# Bluepill related tasks
after 'deploy:start', 'bluepill:start'
after 'deploy:stop', 'bluepill:quit'
after 'deploy:restart', 'bluepill:quit', 'bluepill:start'

namespace :bluepill do
  desc 'Stop processes that bluepill is monitoring and quit bluepill'
  task :quit, :roles => [:app] do
    run "cd #{current_path}; sudo bluepill #{application}_#{rails_env} stop"
    run "cd #{current_path}; sudo bluepill #{application}_#{rails_env} quit"
    sleep 5
  end

  desc 'Load bluepill configuration and start it'
  task :start, :roles => [:app] do
    run "cd #{current_path}; sudo bluepill load #{current_path}/config/server/#{rails_env}/delayed_job.bluepill"
  end

  desc 'Prints bluepills monitored processes statuses'
  task :status, :roles => [:app] do
    run "cd #{current_path}; sudo bluepill #{application}_#{rails_env} status"
  end
end
```

I haven't tested the above yet.

What I am wondering is: what should I put in my `sudoers` file to allow the `deploy` user run just these bluepill related commands as root without a password? On [this page](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2010/02/monitoring-delayed-job-with-bluepill-and-capistrano/) they have mentioned this:

```
deploy ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/bluepill
```

But the path to the bluepill binary would be different in my case. And it would be different for different projects, because of project-specific gemsets. Should I be mentioning each of the binary paths or is there a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use wrappers and aliases:

```
namespace :bluepill do
  task :setup do
    run "rvm alias create #{application} #{rvm_ruby_name_evaluated}"
    run "rvm wrappers #{application} --no-links bluepill"
  end
end
```

so after this task `bluepill` is available via `#{rvm_path}/wrappers/#{application}/bluepill` which will be always the same even if you change ruby version, so it can be added to sudoers for preserving path:

```
deploy ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/my_user/.rvm/wrappers/my_app/bluepill
```

and then the tasks can use:

```
sudo #{rvm_path}/wrappers/#{application}/bluepill ...
```

it is important to note here that the wrapper takes care of loading rvm environment because it was lost by invocation of `sudo` ... but this is just a detail ;)

Comment: This still creates one bluepill binary per application, right? If I have another app, that app's bluepill would have to be added to the sudoers file separately, right? And in the `setup` task you have given above, don't I have to `cd` into the application current path before running the `rvm` commands?

Comment: You do nor have to `cd` because `rvm-capistrano` is controlling your environment not the remote RVM, you need to create separate wrapper per application because `sudo` removes all the environment context set previously by `rvm-capistrano` and the wrappers restore proper environment settings so all ruby is set up correctly, there are other ways to do it - I just made it working from your start code.

Comment: If it isn't too much trouble, could you also tell me what other ways there are? Also, is bluepill only available as a gem? If possible, wouldn't it be just better to install bluepill through the OS package manager, so it is available system-wide?

Comment: from what I read https://github.com/arya/bluepill - you need separate gemset just for bluepill - and use aliased wrappers inside to start / stop application